# jScrollPane resets back to original after class refresh

Tags: php, jquery, refresh, jscrollpane

I have a site which has a section containing a Youtube video and the comments for it. The comments which are inside a div class get refreshed every 5 minutes using the following code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){
        $(".comments").load("test.php .comments");
    }, 300000);
</script>
```

To scroller for the comments is powered by jScrollPane. However after after the comments have refreshed, the scroller disappears and reverts back to the original browser scroller. I have tried adjusting the script above so that is also refreshed the scroller but no hope there.

The container for the comments is as shown below

```
    echo '<div class="comments scroll">';

        $feedURL = curl_init("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$cut}/comments");
            curl_setopt($feedURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($feedURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

        $data = curl_exec($feedURL);
            curl_close($feedURL);

        $sxml = new SimpleXmlElement($data);            

        foreach($sxml->entry as $comment)
            {
            echo '<p>',$comment->content,'</br><i>',$comment->author->name,'</i></br>','</p>';
            }
    echo '</div>';
```

Could someone please advise on how to work around this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){
        $(".comments").load("test.php");

        $('.scroll').jScrollPane();
    }, 300000);   
</script>
```

Comment: this prevents the scroller from reverting back to the default browser style however is doesnt refresh the comments again, it loads the whole site in the comments box

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it thanks to @ThulasiRam's idea. Made a small change though.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   setInterval(function(){
      $(".comments").load("test.php .comments");
      $('.scroll').jScrollPane({showArrows:true});
   }, 300000);   
</script>
```